# UITableViewCell content shifting after selection

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview where each cell has an image to the left of a label and detail label like so:

[image]

It renders just like that as it is supposed to when the tableview first loads, but if I click the cell to navigate to a different view then return to the table view the image shifts to cover part of the label like this:

[image]

The change happens about a second after the tableview appears and it only happens to the cell that was previously selected. Does anyone have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: i had the same problem before. are you using autolayout or not?

Comment: autolayout is enabled, but I haven't set up any constraints for this view

Comment: in my case autolayout is disabled and gave left and top masking for all the view then its working fime

Comment: turning off autolayout fixes the shifting, but now the image view expands to cover the image all the time

Comment: Leave auto layout on, but give your image view explicit constraints to the left side of the cell, centerY, width and height.

Comment: I've given the image view a specific width and height constraint, distance to left side of the content view of the cell and distance to the label. What should I center the y with respect to?

Comment: Selecting the centerY constraint centers it with respect to its superview, which would be the cell's content view in this case (you don't have to choose that, it automatically centers it in the superview).

Comment: I'm not given the option to center y to the content view. Should I center vertically?

Comment: nevermind I could do it the other way around. I'm still getting the same bug though

Comment: Dont center it. Use Leading space and top space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but it's what worked for me. Eventually I just deleted all of the subviews in the cell and readding them. It now works fine without having to mess with constraints. I'm not sure what the cause of the problem was.

Comment: I wonder if it could have been related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681273/uitableviewcell-imageview-changing-on-select/17123367#17123367

Comment: @AdamJack it was for me , for some reason my image view had two bindings instead of 1 , i just deleted the binding and created a new one with another name and it worked! thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue. I was set my custom UIImageView's name as imageView and Now I changed it's name as mImageView and fixed.

Maybe you should rename your imageView @IBOutlet name.

> Incorrect using - Not working properly

```
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
```

> Correct Using

```
@IBOutlet var mImageView: UIImageView!
```

Very strange issue