# UITableView cell Imageview changing its size on click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitableview

When i load the page its normal pls check below image

[image]

and when i click on a row ,then the corresponding image is showing in different size , Please check the below image(when i click 1st and 2nd row)

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue. Here am using SDWebImage for lazy loading of images from url.

My code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;    //count of section
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [names count];    //count number of row from counting array hear cataGorry is An Array
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"service";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier]
        ;
    }

    // Here we use the provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
    // Ensure you use a placeholder image otherwise cells will be initialized with no image

   // cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(5,10,50,60);
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds=YES;
    cell.imageView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imaages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return 80;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
}
```

Comment: fixed by using custom uitableviewcell

Comment: how do you fixed the problem?

Comment: [UItableViewCell imageview changing on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681273/uitableviewcell-imageview-changing-on-select/17123367#17123367) Try above link it solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reload the tableview when it finish loading, the image get the size that it was suppose to have

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Clip image to subviews, and add autolayout to it.

```
[cell.contentView.superview setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

For custom cells, select your image and

[image]

Comment: this is not a custome cell

Comment: `imageView.autoResizingMask` set to `UIViewAutoResizingNone`

Comment: Hmn, It happened like this to me once, but I was on non-ARC project and I was releasing viewController on viewWillDisappear. What do you do when you click a row?

Comment: Try to remove if statement with all it's contents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54365/discussion-between-3r1d-and-bangalore).